# Estou com duvida no uso do get_context_data

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou tentando carregar uma segunda queryset no meu template atraves do get_context_data, quando tento carregar a query ela não mostra no template. segue o codigo:
o objetivo é carregar as cidades filtradas por estado, estou usando HTMX.

MODELS:

```
class DadoPessoal(models.Model):
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pertence_pessoa = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Dados_Pessoais')
    datadenascimento = models.DateField()
    sexo = models.CharField(choices=SEXO, max_length=9)
    nomedamae = models.CharField('Nome da Mãe', max_length=100)
    nomedopai = models.CharField('Nome do Pai', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    nacionalidade = models.CharField(choices=NACIONALIDADE, max_length=20)
    naturalidade = models.ForeignKey(Cidade, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='naturalidade')
    estadodenascimento = models.ForeignKey(Estado, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='estadodenascimento')
    estadocivil = models.CharField(choices=ESTADOCIVIL, max_length=20)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('index')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.pertence_pessoa} | {self.datadenascimento}'
```

VIEWS:

```
class DadoPessoalCreate(CreateView):
    model = DadoPessoal
    template_name = 'pessoas/dadopessoal_form.html'
    form_class = DadoPessoalForm
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    kwargs = super(DadoPessoalCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()

    kwargs.update({
        'pertence': pk
    })
    return kwargs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    queryset_pessoa = Pessoa.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    r_estados = self.request.GET.get('estadodenascimento')

    for ps in queryset_pessoa:
        ps_nome = ps.nome
        ps_cpf = ps.cpf
    context['nome'] = ps_nome
    context['cpf'] = ps_cpf

    if r_estados:
        r = int(r_estados)
        queryset = Cidade.objects.filter(Q(uf=r))
        context['queryset'] = queryset

    return context
```

#OBS: trecho do if, fiz depois de perceber que o a variável r_estados é uma string e não numero, quando Removo esse if e faço o filtro de forma manual exp: queryset = Cidade.objects.filter(Q(uf=1)) a query é filtrada e mostra normalmente, se eu filtrar direto; queryset = Cidade.objects.filter(Q(uf=r_estados))  ela mostra vazia no template.

FORM:
#a vairiavel pertence é para filtrar a pessoa atraves do pk. e ganrantir que o dado perterce a pessoa do pk

```
class DadoPessoalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, pertence, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(DadoPessoalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        filtro_pessoa = Pessoa.objects.get(pk=pertence)
        self.fields['pertence_pessoa'].initial = filtro_pessoa

    class Meta:
        model = DadoPessoal

        fields = [
            'pertence_pessoa',
            'datadenascimento',
            'sexo',
            'nomedamae',
            'nomedopai',
            'nacionalidade',
            'naturalidade',
            'estadodenascimento',
            'estadocivil',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'pertence_pessoa': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase', 'value': 'hidden'}),
            'datadenascimento': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'sexo': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select array-select form-control', 'aria-label': 'example', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
            'nomedamae': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
            'nomedopai': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
            'nacionalidade': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select array-select form-control', 'aria-label': 'example', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
            'naturalidade': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select array-select form-control',
                                                'aria-label': 'example',
                                                'style': 'text-transform:uppercase',

                                                }),
            'estadodenascimento': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                      'aria-label': 'example',
                                                      'style': 'text-transform:uppercase',
                                                      'hx-trigger': 'change',
                                                      'hx-get': '#id_estadodenascimento',
                                                      'hx-post': '{% url "dadopessoal" %}',
                                                      'hx-target': '#id_naturalidade',                                                      
                                                      }),
            'estadocivil': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select array-select form-control', 'aria-label': 'example', 'style': 'text-transform:uppercase'}),
        }
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="form-outline">
  {{form.naturalidade.errors}}
  <label class="form-label">Cidade de Nascimetno:</label>
  <select name="naturalidade" class="form-select array-select form-control" aria-label="exemplo" style="text-transform:uppercase" required="" id="id_naturalidade">
      <option value="" selected=""><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">----------</font></font></option>
      {% for cd in queryset %}
      <option value="{{cd.id}}"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">{{cd}}</font></font></option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Porquê a query não carrega? e e quando uso o if para converter a str em int não está retornando nada. quando uso print para exibir no terminal tanto a variavel que guarda o resultado quanto a variavel do context, mostram que esta funcionando como preciso. mas no template não acertei resolver a questão. posso está usando o get_context_data de forma errada, entendo que esse metodo não recebe por padrão querysete(ate onde entendi) por isso estou colocando tudo no contexto.

Comment: o que acontece se no `views.py` no método `get_context_data` você fizer um print da variável r_estados, esta variável está definida?

Comment: print(r_estados, type(r_estados)) saida = 1 <class 'str'>, esse é o retorno do print dentro do get_context_data, quando seleciono a primeira opção.

Comment: poderia fazer um teste, e remover o Q, fazer a função `filter` direto, igual fez no `Pessoa.objects.filter(pk=pk)`

Comment: print(queryset, type(queryset)) = query_fiiltrada, <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>, retorna o resultado, inicialmente fiz sem Q( ). adicionei ele na tentativa de resolver.

Comment: então foi resolvido? Ainda ocorre o problema?

Comment: continua sem passa esses resultados para o template. se for preciso posto alguns prints.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vejo que o problema pode estar no seu código de filtragem de cidades. Você está fazendo um cast de string para inteiro na linha r = int(r_estados), mas se r_estados for uma string vazia, essa linha vai causar um erro de ValueError.

Uma forma de resolver isso seria verificar se r_estados é uma string vazia antes de tentar fazer o cast para inteiro. Algo assim:

```
if r_estados and r_estados.isdigit():
    r = int(r_estados)
    queryset = Cidade.objects.filter(Q(uf=r))
    context['queryset'] = queryset
```

Outra opção seria usar o método get do dicionário de `request.GET` para tentar obter um valor inteiro para a chave 'estadodenascimento'. Se não conseguir, pode atribuir um valor default (como None ou 0) para a variável r. Assim:

```
r = self.request.GET.get('estadodenascimento', 0)
if r:
    queryset = Cidade.objects.filter(Q(uf=r))
    context['queryset'] = queryset
```

Espero que isso ajude! Se você ainda tiver dúvidas ou precisar de mais ajuda, basta perguntar estou por aqui!

Comment: mas se for uma string vazia ele vai entrar no `IF`?

Comment: Não, pois a condição do if é que r seja diferente de zero. Se r for uma string vazia, ela será convertida para 0 e a condição não será satisfeita.

Comment: é verdade, realmente

Comment: Mesmo olhando e refazendo meu codigo, tentei as dicas que vocês deram, as que encontrei pesquisando, mais continuo com o mesmo problema.

resultado do console:
id da variavel e seu tipo: 1 <class 'int'>
resultado do filtro: <QuerySet [<Cidade: Acrelandia>, <Cidade: Assis_Brasil>, <Cidade: Brasileia>, <Cidade: Bujari>, <Cidade: Capixaba>,'...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

resultado da URL:
[07/Jan/2023 20:03:46] "GET /pessoas/dadopessoal/2/?estadodenascimento=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 159121

E não renderisa no template.